# Prove that a set which satisfies every nonempty subset contains a weak Cauchy sequence must be bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, cauchy-sequences

I got stuck on this problem about weak convergence in normed space. This problem is exercise 9, page 263 in Functional Analysis of Erwin Kreyszig. So the question is basically on the title, let me state it clearly here:

> Let $A$ be a set in a normed space $X$ such that every nonempty subset of $A$ contains a weak Cauchy sequence. Show that $A$ is bounded.

Here, a sequence $(x_n)$ is a weak Cauchy sequence if for every $f' \in X'$, the sequence $(f(x_n))$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ ($X'$ is dual space of $X$: space of all bounded linear operators on $X$). I have no idea how to solve this problem, so I hope someone can give me a hint. Thanks so much.

Comment: do they mean any subset containing an infinite number of elements, then we can create a weak Cauchy sequence from the elements of the set, without repeating any of the element ? in that case it is obvious that an unbounded set contains a sequence that goes to $\infty$ in norm $\|.\|_{X}$, but some of those sequences can converge weakly, for example in a Hilbert space : $x_n = n^{1/4} e_n$ where $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis, then $x_n \overset{weakly}\to 0$

Comment: I think he just means "nonempty", not necessarily "infinite"...But is it important, I asked because the condition is for "every" nonempty subset?

Comment: if the sequence is constant then it converges weakly obviously..

Comment: @user1952009 There must have been a typo in your last comment - $(e_n)$ is certainly bounded. And no, $n^{1/4}e_n$ does not tend weakly to $0$.

Comment: @user1952009 (Replying to a version of your comment with typos fixed:) No, $\sum|c_n|^2<\infty$ does not imply that $|c_n|\le Cn^{-1/2}$.

Comment: @David yes you are right, sorry this was dumb.. hence this proves that if $x_n = e_n a_n$ and $x_n \to 0$ weakly then $|a_n| < C$ for some $C$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x_n\in X$ and $||x_n||$ is unbounded then the Banach-Steinhaus Theorem, also known as the Uniform Boundedness Principle, shows that there exists $\Lambda\in X^*$ such that $\Lambda x_n$ is unbounded. So there is a subsequence $x_{n_j}$ with $|\Lambda(x_{n_j}|\to\infty$; that subsequence has no weakly Cauchy subsequence.

Comment: you use the uniform boundedness principle that saying that if $A$ is unbounded then $\sup_{x \in A} |y(x)|$ is unbounded for some $y \in X^*$, and hence any unbounded sequence doesn't converge weakly ?

Comment: Can I ask why you need to introduce complete of $X$ here? Sorry but I don't see where you use the completeness.

Comment: @user1952009 I don't quite see how to answer that except by what I wrote. A question that refers more spcifically to something I wrote might work better

Comment: @leducquang No reason at all - I was thinking a tiny bit backwards. In fact $X^*$ is complete and $X$ is a collection of bounded linear fucntionals on $X^*$, which is all we use. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Thanks, but your previous version has a line that interests me. You said that $\overline{X}^* = X^*$. Is it true for all normed space $X$? So we have that if $f$ is a bounded linear functional on $X$, it is a bounded linear functional on $\overline{X}$, right?

Comment: @user1952009: It's easy to see that fact. It's the problem 13, page 255 in Erwin Kreyszig's book. To prove it, you just need to use theorem 4.6-1 in the same book.

Comment: @leducquang Yes. This is clear because a bounded linear functional is _uniformly_ continuous.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Thanks, I got it ^^